# how to convert python file into android apk?

Tags: android, python, toolchain

I have developed a GUI software based on wx-python. I can make stand alone windows application with the help of py2exe. I use inno script to make installer(setup) file from .exe that i have created with py2exe. But now i want to make executable(apk) for android OS from my python code. Is there any tool-chain for android, like py2exe for windows or any another way to do so?

Comment: kivy/buildozer?

Comment: buildozer didn't work for me... i tried it also... perhaps it may for i am using wxpython... if you know more how to use buildozer with wxpython then please tell me

Comment: By all means, include such information (what you tried, how the result fell short, and optionally what you think _why_) in the question (using [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41138293/edit)). (I don't.)

Comment: buildozer works with kivy and i developed it with wxpython thats all i mean

Comment: i found something but dont know how to use ...[github miracle2k](https://github.com/miracle2k/py-androidbuild) please see this ... may someone get idea

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately there is no tool.

There is a discussion here:
[Discussion](http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/Android-and-wxPython-td3324637.html)

It is possible when U use Pygame:
[rapt-pygame-example](https://github.com/renpytom/rapt-pygame-example)

Answer (score -2):

class MovieTicketBookingSystem:
def **init**(self, movie_name, total_seats):
self.movie_name = movie_name
self.total_seats = total_seats
self.available_seats = total_seats
self.seats_booked = 0
self.seat_map = {str(seat): False for seat in range(1, total_seats + 1)}

```
def book_ticket(self, num_seats):
    if num_seats <= self.available_seats:
        selected_seats = []
        for seat, status in self.seat_map.items():
            if not status and len(selected_seats) < num_seats:
                selected_seats.append(seat)
                self.seat_map[seat] = True
                self.seats_booked += 1
        self.available_seats -= num_seats
        print(f"Successfully booked {num_seats} seat(s) for {self.movie_name}.")
        print(f"Selected seat(s): {', '.join(selected_seats)}")
    else:
        print("Sorry, there are not enough available seats.")

def show_available_seats(self):
    print("Available seats for", self.movie_name)
    for seat, status in self.seat_map.items():
        if not status:
            print(seat, end=" ")
    print()
```

## Example usage

movie_system = MovieTicketBookingSystem("Avengers: Endgame", 50)

movie_system.show_available_seats()

movie_system.book_ticket(3)
movie_system.book_ticket(5)

movie_system.show_available_seats()

Comment: I think this answer may have been left on the wrong question - please review if this is where you intended to leave this and review the guidelines to answering questions at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer